# Distribution function of a conditional random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $(S,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space, and $R$ and $X$ be two random variables. For some positive number $d$, we have that
$$R=\begin{cases}X \text{ if }X<d,\\d \text{ if } X>d.\end{cases}$$

How to calculated the distibution function $F_R(t)$ based on $F_X(t)$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $R = \min(X,d)$ you have:

$$F_R(t) = \begin{cases}
F_X(t) & & \text{if } t < d, \\[6pt]
1 & & \text{if } t \geqslant d. \\[6pt]
\end{cases} $$

Comment: How do you ensure continuity of $F_R(t)$ at $t=d$?

Comment: You don't - there may be a non-zero probability that $R=d$, in which case you have a jump in the CDF.

Comment: You must ensure a CDF is *right*-continuous, of which, if $F_X$ is, then $F_R$ will be for all $t<d$, and since $\lim\limits_{0>h\to 0} F_R(d+h)=F_R(d)$ so it is okay at $t=d$ and above too.